# How to detect all the browsers that are installed in a system?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Hi guys how to detect all the browsers that are installed in a system.By using Flex

Comment: I'm wondering why you care. The burden of supporting all browsers is on Adobe, so it's their job to iron out all the inter-browser quirks. Giving access to private information like that seems to me a violation of security, not to mention evil. With all due respect, I would say this is none of your business.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that from Flex or, as far as I can tell, from any web application. A web app being able to go through the list of installed applications on client machine is bad from a privacy and security point of view.

Maximum you can do is to read the user agent string from the HTTP headers (which can be easily modified and hence need not be accurate) to check what's the current browser being used to access your application. Even this, you can't do from Flex, you'll have to do it using some server script and send the information to the Flex app.

Answer (score 0):

@Amargosh, while you do have to go through the server page to get client information, you can simply get browser information by executing Javascript from Flex:

```
var result:String = ExternalInterface.call("eval", "navigator.userAgent");
```

This will do the trick.

Comment: That might give you access to the userAgent of the current browser; but will not provide the SWF any information about other browsers installed on the system.

Comment: I know.  I was referencing part of Amargosh's reply.  I guess I should have commented instead.